# How to extract the number of lines of source code in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, jenkins-pipeline, static-analysis

I am trying to configure the thresholds for some SCA tools in a pipeline depending on the number of lines of code per project. My questions is, what would be the best way to compute the number of LOC and pass it onto the SCA stage as a parameter?

The only idea I have is to use environmental variables, but I am unsure if these can be set programmatically after the build has started.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `environment { }` block in a Jenkinfile to set environment variables.

```
environment {
    FOO = 'git@github.com:MyOrg/MyRepo.git'
    BAR = 'SomeVal'
}
```

Then you can access them like so:

`"FOO = ${env.FOO}"`

Comment: I ended up using a simple piped shell script to count the lines in every file and store it in a variable like you described.

For anyone that clicked the thread for its title, here's the script that returns a single number representing the lines of code for all of the java files:

`( find ./ -type f -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l`